# Dependent ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to write a code with two ListBoxes, in which what will be displayed in the second depends on what was selected in the first, but I'm having difficulties in reading what was selected in the first and making this switch (this is my first code using WPF ).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace BMFinder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interação lógica para MainWindow.xam
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> Itens = new List<string>();
            Itens.Add("Armas");
            Itens.Add("Capacete");
            Itens.Add("Amadura");
            Itens.Add("Botas");

            List1.ItemsSource = Itens;

            List<string> Tipo = new List<string>();
            Tipo.Add("Couro");
            Tipo.Add("Placa");
            Tipo.Add("Tecido");

            List<string> Armas = new List<string>();
            Armas.Add("Espadas");
            Armas.Add("Arcos");
            Armas.Add("Lanças");
            Armas.Add("Bestas");

            string selecionado = List1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (selecionado == "Armas")
            {
                List2.Items.Clear();
                List2.ItemsSource = Armas;
            }
            else
            {
                List2.Items.Clear();
                List2.ItemsSource = Tipo;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lot of problems in the code. Urge to check the observablecollection instead of list and data binding basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that uses no data binding.

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<string> Tipo { get; set; }
    private List<string> Armas { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List1.ItemsSource = new List<string>
        {
            "Armas",
            "Capacete",
            "Amadura",
            "Botas"
        }

        this.Tipo = new List<string>
        {
            "Couro",
            "Placa",
            "Tecido"
        }

        this.Armas = new List<string>
        {
            "Espadas",
            "Arcos",
            "Lanças",
            "Bestas"
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = sender as Selector;
        var selectedItem = selector.SelectedItem as string;
        switch (selectedItem)
        {
            case "Armas":
              selector.ItemsSource = this.Armas; break;
            default:
              selector.ItemsSource = this.Tipo; break;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <ListBox x:Name="List1" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />
</Window>
```

Further reading:

[Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview),
[Routed Events Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you need to study up a bit more on how these types of programs work in general.

Programs are separated into sections of code called "methods". Each method runs all the way through until the end. `public MainWindow()` is a special type of method called a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors). constructors run whenever an object is created. The "object" in this case is your `MainWindow`.

`public MainWindow()` is the first bit of code in the window that will run. And it will run *before* the window is even shown.

The line
`string selecionado = List1.SelectedItem.ToString();`
executes immediately after setting up the list of items, and it fails because there *is no* selected item yet. The window hasn't even been shown. The user has had no chance to make a selection.

To accomplish what you're attempting, you'll need to separate your code into multiple methods which will run at different times. One that will set up `MainWindow` at the beginning. And a second to set `List2.ItemsSource` after the selection changes.

Running methods at different times is best done using [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/). Specifically, you can use the [`ListBox.SelectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged) event.

In WPF, there's also data binding, but that's slightly more advance and I won't explain it here.

Answer (score -1):

Use can observable collection for change notifications in a collection. There are many of achieving this, one of the ways is as follows.

Usercontrol.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <!--Base Collection contains keys to decide loading of child collection-->
        <local:Itens x:Key="baseCollection"/>
        
        <!--Child collections-->
        <local:Tipo x:Key="tipo"/>
        <local:Armas x:Key="armas"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Base collection row-->
        <RowDefinition/>
        <!--Child collection container row-->
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Base collection-->
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" 
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource baseCollection}"
             Name="BaseList"/>
    
    <!--Child collection container-->
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
        <!--Data trigger to monitor the change in selected item in listbox baselist
        and load the child collection accordingluy-->
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=BaseList,Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Tipo">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource tipo}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=BaseList,Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Armas">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource armas}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

usercontrol.cs

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Itens : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    public Itens()
    {
        Add("Armas");
        Add("Capacete");
        Add("Amadura");
        Add("Botas");
        Add("Tipo");
    }
}

public class Tipo : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    public Tipo()
    {
        Add("Couro");
        Add("Placa");
        Add("Tecido");
    }
}

public class Armas : ObservableCollection<string>
{
    public Armas()
    {
        Add("Espadas");
        Add("Arcos");
        Add("Lanças");
        Add("Bestas");
    }
}
```